# When we register a deployment pool agent under Deployment group with one of my existing machine, will there be any additional charges?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

1. When we register a deployment pool agent under Deployment group with one of my existing machine, will there be any additional charges?
2. How many such agents can I create and use? Is there any limits? I am thinking of a scale of about 500 agents. Is that possible?
3. Deployment pool agent upper limits
4. costing if any, in deployment groups

Comment: Did you look at the documentation by any chance?

Comment: I had went through the documentation as below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops
could not find details on pricing or scale limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the microsoft website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=self-hosted

> For self-hosted parallel jobs, you can register any number of self-hosted agents in your organization. We charge based on the number of jobs you want to run at a time, not the number of agents registered.

This means that, in a job, we can add as many self-hosted agents, from the deployment group and all the agents in a job, will run in parallel, without any additional costs.

Answer (score -1):

A deployment pool is a set of target servers available to the organization. It is not billed based on the number of agents in your pool, but how many parallel jobs you purchase. There is no charge for the deployment pool itself.

For public projects that are self-hosted, you can have unlimited parallel jobs running. For private projects, you can have one job and one additional job for each active Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber who is a member of your organization. If the free tier is no longer sufficient for your self-hosted private project, you can purchase more. See more info about parallel job from [Configure and pay for parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=self-hosted).

---

Updated:

Take the private project as an example. There are 10 agents in your deployment pool that you want to deploy. If you only have one parallel job then there will be 10 jobs running in sequence. If you purchase two parallel jobs, up to two jobs can run in parallel at the same time. The overall deployment time is roughly reduced by half.

There isn't an upper limit on the number of agents that can be registered in the deployment pool.

Comment: 1. in the Deployment group, Azure DevOps > Org > Project > Deployment Groups > we can add a deployment group

2. inside the deployment group, we can register any number of agents right?

3.  also, all the agents will execute simultaneously(in parallel) right? 
here we not restricting the number of agents nor i need to purchase parallel jobs right

Comment: 1. Inside the deployment group, you can register any number of agents. 2. "all the agents will execute simultaneously(in parallel) right" - No. Whether to run in parallel depends on whether you set **Targets to deploy to in parallel** to "Multiple" or "One target at a time". Whether jobs **can** run in parallel depends on how many parallel jobs you purchase. For example, if you set "Targets to deploy to in parallel" to "Multiple" and set "Maximum number of target in parallel" to 10.

Comment: If you haven't purchased any parallel jobs, only one job will run on the agent at one time, even though you have set the maximum number to10.  As many jobs as you want to run at the same time, you need to purchase as many parallel jobs. Hope the above explanation can help you.